# what is the code need to apply for CustomFonts in lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit

i have created custom font "font.res" file using resource.jar file in lwuit,now i want to apply this Custom font to my Textarea Component,how to apply custom font any sample code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add into a text area,

```
ta.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(Font.getBitmapFont("fontname"));
```

fontname- the name you gave to font in res file

If not you can do it by,
in resource editor, open **theme**, double click the component you want to set the font and select font tab,
untick **"derive font"**, tick "new font" and choose your font,
save res file and add it into your j2me project

Comment: should we need to generate whole project using resource editor?in my case,i just have created customfont using ResourceEditor jar file,that  i want apply to Component in my project?can i able to apply without generating the wholeproject using Resource Editor?

Comment: not the whole project, u have to create the font as you wish and the theme, if you are using more than one font it's better to use your component with this   ta.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(Font.getBitmapFont("fontname"));